ng lint cannot find module '@typescript-eslint/utils'
I recently added linting to my Angular project, which worked fine initially, but has recently stopped working. When I run ng lint I get the following error message:
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@typescript-eslint/utils' Require stack:

C:\Projects\TestProj\Web\node_modules@angular-eslint\utils\dist\eslint-plugin\ast-utils.js
C:\Projects\TestProj\Web\node_modules@angular-eslint\utils\dist\index.js
C:\Projects\TestProj\Web\node_modules@angular-eslint\eslint-plugin\dist\rules\component-class-suffix.js
C:\Projects\TestProj\Web\node_modules@angular-eslint\eslint-plugin\dist\index.js
C:\Projects\TestProj\Web\node_modules\angular-eslint\dist\index.js
C:\Projects\TestProj\Web\eslint.config.js

I have tried:
npm i @angular-eslint/utils
npm install
npm clean-install
ng build

I'm pretty new to Angular so please let me know if I've missed anything obvious. Here's my package.json file:
  "name": "testProj",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "serve:ssr:testProj": "node dist/testProj/server/server.mjs",
    "build-prod": "ng build",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-eslint/utils": "^18.3.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/ssr": "^18.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^17.0.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^18.1.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.18.0",
    "angular-eslint": "18.3.1",
    "eslint": "^9.9.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.5.3",
    "typescript-eslint": "8.2.0"
  }
}

Let me know if you'd like any more info. Thanks.

I found the issue. Running npm i @typescript-eslint/utils fixed it. I had mistakenly previously tried installing the package named @angular-eslint/utils.
This was a pretty silly mistake but I'm going to leave the post up anyway since there aren't any other search results for this error message.
